# How to sort NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: cocoa, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have  NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary(NSString objects). One of NSString object is actually a date, and i need to sort NSMutableArray based on that date and I don't want it to sort dates as strings. How can i make it?

Comment: I'd also consider building classes for your data model, since you can implement a straightforward compare: method with NSDate objects. Using mutable dictionaries like this can often get confusing once you pass a certain point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your array contains dictionaries that contain strings and you want to sort on those strings... as dates. Something like this perhaps:

```
[someArray sortWithOptions: 0 usingComparator: ^(id inObj1, id inObj2) {
    NSDate      *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString: [inObj1 objectForKey: @"dateString"]];
    NSDate      *date2 = [NSDate dateWithString: [inObj2 objectForKey: @"dateString"]];

    return [date1 compare: date2];
}];
```

Comment: Well, NSMutableArray doesn't have such method as "sortWithOptions".

Comment: It was introduced in 10.6

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_31

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCHBAHB) method.  For example:

```
NSInteger comparator( NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2, void *context )
{
  return [[d1 objectForKey:@"date"] compare:[d2 objectForKey:@"date"]];
}

// In some method:
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingFunction:comparator context:nil];
```

*Note: This is not tested.*